# I'm closed out of my Azure DevOps organization

Tags: azure, repository, devops, repo

I created an Azure Devops organization using my hotmail account.
For this reason, I am the owner of this organization.
Then I wanted to bind this organization to an Azure Active Directory, so I went here and I attached my Azure AD
[image]

Then by mistake I added a new user to my Organization, however I chose a user belonging to another Azure AD so he is seen as an external user here.
Finally, I removed the hotmail user from the users page. As a result, the hotmail user is still the owner
[image]

, however he is not a member of the organization any more, so I can't enter any more:
[image]

Of course I may click "Request Access", however this request will be sent to the same hotmail account who is owner but is NOT a user... deadlock!

Can you help me please with an hint, I need to access my repos and Azure devops pipelines.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I found it. [This is the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/resolve-orphaned-organization?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) which solved this problem.
Briefly, for organizations connected to Azure AD if the Owner and all other Project Collection Administrators are inactive in Azure AD, you can transfer ownership to another user.